# Objc Cocoa MRC - Released and autoreleased objectsI have to write him up to see application

Tags: objective-c, metal

I'm writing a C++ application  using Metal API (objective C) and MRC (Manual Reference Counting). I have a very limited experience with ObjC. Most of the Metal API objects are defined as protocols and created as an object returned from C-function or other object's method (ex. MTLDevice newBufferWithLength). To know how to release objects created this way I need to know if they have been set autoreleased or not (I can't call release an autoreleased object with retain count 1 for instance). The problem is I can't find any description in Metal API documentation which would answer this question. I've only read in user guide that all so called lightweight objects are created autoreleased. There are three examples of autoreleased objects but not sure if I can just assume that rest of the objects are not autoreleased. In cocoa many objects also may be created without alloc+init, being returned from a static method (ex NSString string) so the problem seems not to be only Metal related.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why would you start a new ObjectiveC project without using ARC?

Comment: Wonder seconded, except without the words after project. However, it's too common on Stack Overflow, to be critical of askers' intentions. Let us keep it at interest and not move to contempt.

Comment: Because I need unified binary (x86 and x64) in one and as far as I know ARC is x64 exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

The usual Objective-C rule is that creating scope is also responsible to release object. So, in virtually all cases, except well-documented exceptions, returned object is autoreleased (both returned through return value or out-arguments). More correct way to see it is that object is always returned with +0 *scope-local retain count*, so you are expected to retain it if needed. Reading the manual it seems that Metal API is one of Apple's frameworks, so it should follow this rule unless warned with bold statements. C functions in Objective-C are also expected to behave that way. (There is no difference between a method and a function in terms of resource management.)

For that "alloc-init vs. [NSString string]" part: MRC code either returns [NSString string], which is already +0, or [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease]. Otherwise it breaks the convention. Exceptions are `-[init]` and `+[new...]` methods itself that return +1. Under ARC there is no difference between alloc-init/string, because ARC knows the convention and does the right thing, optimizing excessive retains/releases where possible.

Also note that `-[retainCount]` is meaningless and "considered harmful", because you never know how many retain-autorelease calls were performed and what objc-runtime accounting is in effect even with your own objects.

ARC is really a great option unless you're writing some sort of Objective-C -to- Whatever bridge, where retain counts and/or cycles must be managed explicitly due to lack of context. It doesn't take anything from you, giving in most cases a big advantage of not managing resources at all.

Comment: I'm not sure if Metal follows this rule. There is no word in APIs description that it creates object in an unussual way. For instance: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLDevice_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MTLDevice/newBufferWithLength:options: In Metal

Comment: I'm not sure if Metal follows this rule. There is no word in APIs description that it creates object in an unussual way. For instance: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLDevice_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MTLDevice/newBufferWithLength:options: . But in the Metal programming guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Cmd-Submiss/Cmd-Submiss.html in section "Transient and Non-transient Objects in Metal" they suggest that MTLBuffer may be created in a different way.

Comment: "Created autoreleased" means they returned like -[string] +0, and "different way" is described a little below – via newWhateverWithArguments(), obviously +1, as name starts with "new". It is about convenience (light objects expected to be released, so already +0, heavy objects expected to be created rarely, so +1, so under mrc you don't call excessive retain/releases). That's why we have both -[string] and alloc-init – they are [in]convenient in different places. This is NOT about new ownership rules.

Comment: Thank you. You opened my eyes. Metal objects described as transient are created through methods/functions without "new" keyword in the name like for instance "commandBuffer" which creates autoreleased MTLCommandBuffer object. On the other side we have non-transient (non autoreleased) objects created through methods/functions containing "new" keyword like newBufferWithLength. I'm curious why Apple hasn't described this rule in Metal guides.

Comment: @gringo001 Because resource management rules in Objective-C world is common sense. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH (google Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide if link is broken).